# Spring integration errors after migration to spring 5

Tags: spring, migration, spring-integration, integration

I have been using Spring integration (different types of channels) with Spring 4 for some time. After i tried to upgrade my environment to Spring 5, they stopped working with errors such as the following:

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@c192373]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null, failedMessage=GenericMessage

Sample channel creation/registration is as follows:

deltaupdatedchannel = new DirectChannel();
deltaupdatedchannel.setBeanName("deltaupdatedcontroller");

```
    serviceActivator = new ServiceActivatingHandler(deltaSummaryController, "updateDelta2");
    handlerlist.add(serviceActivator);
    
    
    
    beanFactory.registerSingleton("deltaupdatedcontroller", deltaupdatedchannel);
    beanFactory.initializeBean(deltaupdatedchannel, "deltaupdatedcontroller");
    deltaupdatedchannel.subscribe(serviceActivator);
```

Channels are used to make the following call:
this.deltaupdatedcontrollerchannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(summarydto).build());

And channel calls the following code:

public void updateDelta2(DeltaSummaryDTO dto) {

```
    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
            "/topic/updatedelta", dto);
}
```

Here messagingTemplate is org.springframework.messaging.core.MessageSendingOperations.

How can i make them work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share, please, with us the reason doing that `registerSingleton()`. Why just plain bean registration is not enough for you?

To fix that problem you need to call also `initializeBean(Object existingBean, String beanName)` after that `registerSingleton()`.

However there is no guarantee that this will be the end of errors. I would suggest to revise a design in favor of normal bean definitions, not that manual one...

Comment: This is somewhat legacy code. These are some member variables of a service class. So do you recommend them to be defined as beans in some configuration class? Some channels are known before runtime but some channels' count is only known at runtime so they must be created manually. (as far as i understand) Isnt it so?

Comment: I understand that initializebean() call must be made before registersingleton. I did it. I still get those exceptions when code tries to call send() on those channels: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [..]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null, failedMessage=GenericMessage [..] at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)

Comment: This must be made after `registerSingleton()`. And the problem is not only with channels: you do register other beans manually as well . So, they have to be initialized too

Comment: I saw the following in the documentation: "The given instance is supposed to be fully initialized; the registry will not perform any initialization callbacks". Channels are the only beans that are registered manually.  Anyway it still doesnt work. (whatever works in spring 4 doesnt work any more) I still have the following errors: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@19329737]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null,

Comment: The exception you mention has nothing to do with channels. It is about a subscriber to that channel and looks like that one is not initialized. It is really better to rethink your logic in favor of bean definitions. There are many many components which just cannot live outside of the DI container …

Comment: I dont understand it. Here is where the exception is thrown: this.deltaupdatedcontrollerchannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(summarydto).build()); And here is stacktrace after that line: 
 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:578)
 at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)

Comment: And what is listening from that channel? The send is one side, but show, please, another one. And don’t do that in the comments: the code is fully not readable. Respect our free time helping you…

Comment: It is such a short code so i will share it: (it is just a websocket call) public void updateDelta2(DeltaSummaryDTO dto) {
          
     this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
             "/topic/updatedelta", dto);
    }

Comment: That’s still send part. Show, please , the receiving one.

Comment: channel calls that specific method. That call (convertandsend) just sends its input to a web page. MessageingTemplate belongs to spring so i dont think i need to share it here. Here is the root cause of the exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BeanFactory must not be null
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
 at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.getBeanOfType(IntegrationUtils.java:110) Do you still think that this has nothing to do with spring integration? I will also edit my original question.

Comment: I didn’t say that it has nothing to do with Spring Integration. According your error it fully does, but it is not clear yet what you don’t show us which has to be initialized properly. Can you show the whole stack trace? Perhaps it will reveal the code you need to share, so we can determine what has to be initialized yet?

Comment: How that `updateDelta2` method is tied with your channel? Show that code, please.

Comment: That service activator has to be registered and initialized. That’s the part you are missing